# Android Application

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My question: I have successfully setup two `Activities` which are executing in their respective threads but the problem is I'm not able to put some delay in between these two threads i.e i need to execute t1(low priority) first and t2 let's say after 30 seconds. And I also want to pause t1 when t2 start executing.

Code:

```
final Thread t1 = new Thread() {
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            Intent First=new Intent("com.example.realtimeassignment.Tasky1");
            startActivity(First);
        }   
    }
};

Thread t2 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try{
            sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            Intent Second=new Intent("com.example.realtimeassignment.Tasky2");
            startActivity(Second);
        }

        handler1.postDelayed(this, 60000);                               
    }
};

t1.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
t2.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

t1.start();
//I need some delay here
t2.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is your task:

```
final Handler handler - new Handler();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
     public void run() {
           handler.post(new Runnable() {
                 public void run(){
                     t2.start(); // after 30 sec 2d thread will be executed
                     t1.sleep(?) // ? = how long time?
                 }
           });
     }
};
```

Here is a timer:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, 30000L);//30 000 = 30sec
```

In case you want to stop `Timer` use this code:

```
if(timer != null){
   timer.cancel();
   timer.purge();
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

And pause the `thread` you may set as `sleep(TIME);` TIME = duration of executing `thread` #2.

*UPDATE*

```
final Thread t1 = new Thread() {
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            Intent First=new Intent("com.example.realtimeassignment.Tasky1");
            startActivity(First);
        }   
    }
};

Thread t2 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try{
            sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            Intent Second=new Intent("com.example.realtimeassignment.Tasky2");
            startActivity(Second);
        }
        handler1.postDelayed(this, 60000);                               
    }
};

t1.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
t2.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

t1.start();
//I need some delay here
final Handler handler - new Handler();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
       handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
               t2.start(); // after 30 sec 2d thread will be executed
               t1.sleep(?) // ? = how long time?
            }
       });
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, 30000L);
```

Comment: Thanks Yurets, I guess your code is working fine so far but how will i set the priority of this timerTask? I want its priority to be high and plus i want my already executing task paused when this timertask start executing after 30 sec. Can you help me out with that?

Comment: you don't have to set priority to the task. It is like a bridge. From your code you start `t1.start();`, inside this code I give you just enter what to do AFTER 30 seconds. You may leave priorities as you have now, it is not a problem.

Comment: Ok cool. But how will i pause the activity already executing? when this timertask start executing.

Comment: Scenario: I have two threads, thread1 is already running and of low priority, thread2 is of high priority and it will start running after 30 sec but when thread2 start executing i want my thread1 paused.

Comment: see my updated answer. that is how it must looks like. Pause an `Activity`? I'm sorry? You cannot pause the `Activity`.

Comment: After word *UPDATE* in my answer it is the final answer. just copy that code and change symbol "?" which I set to the time you want your `thread` #1 to sleep (to pause). If it did solve your problem and you're satisfied with solution, please, accept the answer, so question will be closed. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, yurets. It's working fine though i'm still not able to pause the first thread but rest of the code is according to the requirements.

Comment: Actually i am running a mp3 sound track in my first thread and i want it paused when thread2 start executing after 30 seconds.

Comment: if you want to pause not `Thread`, but `MediaPlayer`, so just say: `mMediaPlayer.stop();`. Just replace the line with `t1.sleep();`.

Comment: Dude, you are freaking awesome.

Comment: Glad we did! Happy coding :) don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: I'm a newbee to all this so, can you tell me from where can i accept your answer?

Comment: next to the header of my question is checkmark, if you hover it goes green, just click on it. thanks :)